# jQuery no smooth .animate() transitions when using .stop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-animate

I've build a sticky navigation that disappears when the user scrolls down, and re-appears when he/she scrolls back up. This is so there's more content visible on smaller screens when, for example, reading an article.

The problem I had was animations queue build-up, but I was able to fix it using `.stop()`
However, this created another problem, which is no smooth animations. When you keep scrolling up, the `.stop()` gets executed, and then the scroll-up animation continues, creating a weird animation effect.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {

    var $menu = $('.mobile-menu');
    var previousTop = $menu.offset().top;

    $(document).scroll(function() {
        // Determine scroll position
        var top = $(this).scrollTop();

        // Check if user is scrolling up
        if (top < previousTop) {
            // .stop() prevents animation queue build-up
            $menu.animate({
                top: 0
            }, 200);
        }
        else {
            // .stop() prevents animation queue build-up
            $menu.animate({
                top: -$menu.outerHeight()
            }, 200);
        }
        previousTop = top;
    });

  });
});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/8wwtLda3/

I know I can fix this using CSS transitions, but the script has to be reusable, and editing the CSS files isn't always an options.

Any tips on how to get smooth jQuery animations, without a queue building up?

---

**SOLUTION**: Thanks to Fonzy for telling me about `.queue()` I was able to fix this.
http://jsfiddle.net/8wwtLda3/1/

Comment: maybe queue(): http://api.jquery.com/queue/? I recently used it without knowing it existed. Helped my transitions :)

Comment: @Fonzy Thanks, that did the trick! I've added the code I ended up using in a new fiddle. Post your solutions as an answer so I can accept it and close this question. Thanks :)